# Angular unit testing initialize "nameless" controller in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I'm curious as to how I would go about unit testing what I think is an anonymous controller inside of a directive.

**directive.js**

```
app.directive('directive',
    function() {
        var controller = ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.add = function() { ... };
        }];

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                args: '='
            },
            templateUrl: '...',
            controller: controller
        };
    }
};
```

Is a controller defined as such able to be unit tested?  I have tried to initialize it several different ways.  Currently I have it setup like this:

```
describe('The directive', function() {
    var element,
        scope,
        controller;

    var args = {
        ...
    }

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(module('path/to/template.html'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            scope.args = args;
            element = angular.element('<div directive></div>');
            template = $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
            controller = element.$controller;       
        });
    });

    // assertions go here
});
```

I keep getting `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating ...)` errors, so I don't think I am initializing the controller correctly.  I mainly want to know if something like this is unit testable without changing the directive's source code at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you are trying to do is possible. However, I do know that there is a much easier way and that is to make it a standard controller. (You seem to be aware of this already but it's worth pointing out.)

The logic in a controller really shouldn't be dependent on the directive anyway so by making a named controller you are separating concerns which is a good thing. [You can even see this used in recommended style guides for AngularJS.](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y075) Once you have the controller set up properly you shouldn't have any issues testing it. Splitting it out like that also helps in doing proper dependency injection making for simpler code and simpler tests.

Comment: IMHO this is the answer, I'm doing tests for several years now, including 2 for angular itself. Trying to do something different will bring you a lot of frustration and conclusion that this is the best solution